# Add MAMP Pro Vhosts with script

Tags: apache, mamp, virtualhost

I am trying to add add Virtual Host to MAMP Pro with a script that I am writing. Much of the documentation out there covers adding vhosts with MAMP (free, not Pro). What I am trying to do is add the vhost, restart MAMP Pro, and move on to the next part of my script.

I've tried editing `httpd.conf` at `~/Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/httpd.conf`, but when MAMP Pro restarts it is overwritten each time despite the comments on `~line 915`, which say to add Include files to add functionality.

The closest someone has gotten to getting an answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12359199/automatic-virtual-hosts-with-mamp-pro) where the answerer suggests editing the plist files that MAMP Pro uses to generate the new config file each time.

Comment: Can you please explain how you got to do it in the end? Is the answer all you need to do, or what is it I need to do with it, exactly? I tried editing the ~/Library/Application\ Support/appsolute/MAMP\ PRO/settings3.plist file but I'm not sure how to edit it so that the vhosts would appear in the MAMP Pro GUI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit template: MAMP -> File -> Edit Template -> Apache -> httpd.conf and add line at the bottom of the file (change path iy you need, and create your custom conf file):

```
Include /Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/extra/myVhosts.conf
```

Then add what you want in this file...